# Angular array: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I am trying to display information from a web service but am getting the following error *"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'bu' of undefined"*. However the data that I wish to display is showing correctly. Here is a copy of the web service response and code.

```
{
    "bu": [
           {
            "id": 1,
            "bcluster": "R03 - Information Technology",
            "bsector": "P20 - CA SA",
            "bgroup": "319 - ITM as a Service (passthrough)",
            "bunit": "-"
           },
           {
            "id": 2,
            "bcluster": "R03 - Information Technology",
            "bsector": "Q04 - Information Management & Applications",
            "bgroup": "P36 - Softworks",
            "bunit": "001 - Softworks Licence & Maintenanc"
           }
         ]
}
```

HTML

```
  <ul class="list-group"  *ngFor="let item of vals.bu">
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">{{item.id}}</button>
        <input type="text" class="input-group btn btn-light" [(ngModel)]="item.bunit">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

TS

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<DataResponse>(this.api.getBU()).subscribe(data => {
      this.vals = data;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use safe navigation operator or *ngIf inorder to handle the delay of response from your asynchronous request,

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">{{item?.id}}</button>
        <input type="text" class="input-group btn btn-light" [(ngModel)]="item?.bunit">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </li>
```

EDIT

As mentioned in the comment, handle the null in your ngFor and remove it in the ngModel

```
<ul class="list-group"  *ngFor="let item of vals?.bu">
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">{{item.id}}</button>
        <input type="text" class="input-group btn btn-light" [(ngModel)]="item.bunit">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but I get this error ''[Angular] Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 13 in [item?.bunit=$event]

Comment: remove it from ngModel

Comment: *ngFor="let item of vals?.bu">

Comment: @eohdev I have answered that. Please check.

Comment: @AmitChigadani haha! why do you say :) look at the comment

Comment: Why didnt you add that in your answer first. That comment came only after my answer.

Comment: well i do accept that, btw its OP's choice. but the actual answer to his problem was the one initiatlly mentioned no need to argue dude :)

Comment: both of you are geniuses, no fight pls :) . Unfortunately can only accept one answer

Comment: ROFLMAO! I feel kind of silly, if you have taken it so serious :)

Comment: thannnnnkkk you, it works for me using angular 9, using "?" operator

Answer (score 2):

You should use safe navigation operator for `vals?.bu`. Because you are getting `vals` asynchronously.

```
<ul class="list-group"  *ngFor="let item of vals?.bu">
    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">{{item.id}}</button>
        <input type="text" class="input-group btn btn-light" [(ngModel)]="item.bunit">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```